# What brand is this buzzer?

Tags: speakers

I have been searching for this buzzer for weeks.  Does anyone know what brand it is? It is a surface mount buzzer.  I need to know the brand.

Approximate dimensions: 8.7 mm x 8.7 mm x 3.25 mm

[image: Speaker]

Comment: SMD speaker, maybe?

Comment: More like SMD buzzer.

Comment: Is the mark in the corner a "+" sign, or the state of Texas?

Comment: @RonBeyer I think it’s the Swiss Flag

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Or the Red Cross flag... because as far as I can tell, TI doesn't manufacture SMD "buzzers" or "piezo speakers".

Comment: It is a Plus Sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/css-i4b20-smt-tr.pdf) one, or some similar model by another manufacturer. It’s not uncommon for there to be compatible parts from different suppliers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Spehro!  That is it!